# How to get string value of TextView from an Activity to external non-activity class in Android

Tags: java, android

**I'm just new to Android development and I'm trying to make an OCR app. The problem is, I got a String value to my TextView on my main activity and I don't know how to get its value from an external java class.**

> This is my external java class naming TessOCR.java. I want to get the value of TextView in main activity to use it as a string for language.

`String language = [i want the value to be here]`

```
    public class TessOCR {

    private Tes

    sBaseAPI mTess;
        public TessOCR() {

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mTess = new TessBaseAPI();
           // AssetManager assetManager=
            String datapath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DemoOCR/";
            String language = "eng+tha+kor+tam+ces";
           // AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            File dir = new File(datapath + "/tessdata/");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            mTess.init(datapath, language);

        }



        public String getOCRResult(Bitmap bitmap) {

            mTess.setImage(bitmap);
            String result = mTess.getUTF8Text();

            return result;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mTess != null)
            mTess.end();
    }
}
```

> This is my code in main activity where I have my TextView named text.

```
public void selectlanguage(View view) {
    final CharSequence languages[] = new CharSequence[]{"English", "Arabic","Russian","Polish","Tamil","Latin","German", "Thai", "Tagalog", "Czech", "Spanish(Old)","Spanish", "Korean", "Chinese(Traditional)", "Chinese(Simplified)"};


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Language");
    builder.setItems(languages,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            Button btnlanguage;
            TextView text;
            // the user clicked on colors[which]
            String lang;

            switch (which){
                case 0:
                    btnlanguage= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    btnlanguage.setText("English");
                    text.setText("eng");
                    lang = "eng";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    btnlanguage= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    btnlanguage.setText("Arabic");
                    lang = "ara";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btnlanguage= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    btnlanguage.setText("Russian");
                    lang = "rus";
                    break;
                     default:
                    btnlanguage= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
                    btnlanguage.setText("English");
                    lang = "eng";
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to get the value from a `TextView` in a standard class? Or do you simply want to store the value from the `TextView` in a property from the class?

Comment: what you mean `get its value from an external java class` ?

Comment: Store the textview string from main activity in shared prefs. Pass the activity context into your non-activity class and from there you should be able to access the stored pref.

Answer (score 0):

Your Class should have a **Context** object :

```
public class YourClass {
   private Context context;
   public YourClass(Context context){
     this.context=context;
   }
   public void doSomething(){
        TextView txtView = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.YourTextViewID);
        Log.d("result :",txtView.getText().toString());
   }
 //..
}
```